# What units are AVHRR channels 1-3 in?

Tags: google-earth-engine, satellite, noaa

I'm trying to combine pre-1981 imagery from [NOAA's AVHRR](https://www.avl.class.noaa.gov/saa/products/search?datatype_family=AVHRR) with post-1981 imagery from [Google Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_CDR_AVHRR_SR_V5) for some urban land cover prediction tasks, but have found that the channels 1-3 appear to be in substantially different units between the two datasets.

In Google Earth Engine, channels 1-2 can range from 1-10,000, but in the NOAA data they seem to never go above about 80. Is there some documentation available online about the intended units of the NOAA and Earth Engine data? Are both in albedos?